# Reserved words in Google Custom Search API

Tags: google-custom-search

I am working with the Google Search API, and I am running into some trouble. This request (in Python, using the requests library) works fine

```
res = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1", params={
    "cx": <key1>,
    "key": <key2>,
    "alt": "json",
    "num": 2,
    "q": "cat sock ship hero monkey baby match"
})
```

and returns results with the syntax according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list)

However, this request does not work:

```
res = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1", params={
    "cx": <key1>,
    "key": <key2>,
    "alt": "json",
    "num": 2,
    "q": "cat sock ship hero monkey footnoteref baby match"
})
```

it returns this:

```
{'kind': 'customsearch#search',
 'queries': {'request': [{'count': 2,
    'cx': '<key>',
    'inputEncoding': 'utf8',
    'outputEncoding': 'utf8',
    'safe': 'off',
    'searchTerms': 'cat sock ship hero monkey baby footnoteref match',
    'title': 'Google Custom Search - cat sock ship hero monkey baby footnoteref match',
    'totalResults': '0'}]},
 'searchInformation': {'formattedSearchTime': '0.22',
  'formattedTotalResults': '0',
  'searchTime': 0.218722,
  'totalResults': '0'},
 'spelling': {'correctedQuery': 'cat sock ship hero monkey baby footnote ref match',
  'htmlCorrectedQuery': 'cat sock ship hero monkey baby <b><i>footnote ref</i></b> match'},
 'url': {'template': 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q={searchTerms}&num={count?}&start={startIndex?}&lr={language?}&safe={safe?}&cx={cx?}&sort={sort?}&filter={filter?}&gl={gl?}&cr={cr?}&googlehost={googleHost?}&c2coff={disableCnTwTranslation?}&hq={hq?}&hl={hl?}&siteSearch={siteSearch?}&siteSearchFilter={siteSearchFilter?}&exactTerms={exactTerms?}&excludeTerms={excludeTerms?}&linkSite={linkSite?}&orTerms={orTerms?}&relatedSite={relatedSite?}&dateRestrict={dateRestrict?}&lowRange={lowRange?}&highRange={highRange?}&searchType={searchType}&fileType={fileType?}&rights={rights?}&imgSize={imgSize?}&imgType={imgType?}&imgColorType={imgColorType?}&imgDominantColor={imgDominantColor?}&alt=json',
  'type': 'application/json'}}
```

The only difference between the two queries is that the latter has the word "footnoteref" in it. I did not find in the documentation anything about this word and its impact on the API's behavior. What is happening? Is there a way to disable this behavior, or a list of reserved words? For now, I am just going to remove the offending word from the query, but I am afraid I am going to play a whack-a-mole game of removing words each time other offending word pops out.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure there is a page in the domain you're searching that contains all of these words?  If you go to google.com, put `cat sock ship hero monkey footnoteref baby match site:<custom-search-domain>` in the search bar, do you get any results?

Comment: @MikePatrick If I put those words on the google site by hand, it returns results for the corrected words. But, still, I don't search in a custom site, I am trying to use the api as a human would do, without a site.

Comment: I see.  I get a single result when I try this, using the API explorer *or* python w/`requests`.  I did notice that adding `site:*` to the query in the browser was initially giving me an empty set, but is now returning this SO question as the only result.  Using the API, the single result I get is this PDF: http://purl.access.gpo.gov/GPO/LPS9006  Odd behavior indeed.  If you add `"fileType": "pdf"` to your `params`, do you still come up empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I searched on google for both `"cat sock ship hero monkey footnoteref baby match"` and `"cat sock ship hero monkey baby match"`.

You said that `"cat sock ship hero monkey footnoteref baby match"` doesn't return anything, and that's because Google actually suggests a different search: `'cat sock ship hero monkey baby footnote ref match'`.

When you don't have results, you should remove a word from the search (I will start with the last word) and try again. Or you should just try with the suggested search, like: `'cat sock ship hero monkey baby footnote ref match'`.

The search works fast, I suggest you to implement the following technique:

- a) Your search contains less than 3-4 words. You should repeat the
  search but add a new word from google's `'correctedQuery'`
  suggestion.
- b) Your search contains more than 4 words. You should remove the last
  word or a "link word" like "for", "and".. and repeat the search.

Good luck.